# Is this vulnerable to dom-based xss?

Tags: javascript, html, xss, security

I have a disagreement with a security auditor, whether a snippet of html/js is vulnerable to XSS or not.

In short this is it:

```
<html>
<form name="myform" action="page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input name="field" type="text" size="50" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
function validate()
{
  var str=document.myform.field.value;
  alert("Error in " + str);
  return false
}
</script>
</html>
```

So, my auditor says that this can be vulnerable to DOM-based XSS, but has not yet given me an example.

I personally think that it is not, since because of the + inside alert, str is a string so it's not executed. For example if someone provides "document.cookie" in the form and hits submit, then the alert box is going to print "Error in document.cookie" (and not the actual cookie).

Comment: I don't see how this is vulnerable (it requires that you *type stuff into the field* and then submit the form yourself!). And even if it were, it would just allow you to... hack yourself. Yay!

Comment: Is this the whole form, or is anything returned from PHP to repopulate fields or display on screen?

Comment: Michael no nothing is returned, this is supposed to be dom-xss not reflective.
yes @Jon, it's kinda of self-xss I guess. 
The ultimate question is if someone can somehow display his cookies or execute javascript code he has written in the 'field' of the form, by pressing the submit button, going through the alert box. E.g. Can I somehow put something in the form and upon hitting submit I get an alert with my document.cookie?

Comment: Well all the cookies a site provides are *already immediately available* via the browser, or at least they are in Firefox and Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I made a jsFiddle if anyone wants to play around with it and try to inject some javascript in that input. http://jsfiddle.net/GwgQW/

Comment: thanks @Leo, that is so cool. After playing with it for a while, I think what stops the 'xss' is that document.myform.field.value returns a String type or something like that. Still trying to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this could be a potential threat is if you are including scripts that are not under your control from an untrustworthy source.

- The malicious script could overwrite `alert` to be another function.  For example, it could send the data passed to `alert` to its own servers.
- The malicious script could overwrite the value of `document.myform.field` with an object containing a `value` property.  The `alert` could be thus made to display a message that looked like a different error message, such as:

> Error in authentication.  Please go to www.phisherman.com and enter your user name and password.

If you are linking to scripts from untrustworthy sources, you have *much* greater security concerns than the above.

If you are linking to no such untrustworthy scripts, then no, this is not vulnerable to DOM-based XSS.  `form.field.value` contains a string.  It is not evaluated as script, escape characters have no effect, the string contained in the textbox will be displayed in the alert window.  Nothing a user enters in that field could be used to harm your servers or corrupt your data based on the code you've posted.

I'd say that if your auditor is concerned with "DOM-based XSS" where-in a user might cause harm to your servers by manipulating the DOM, your auditor does not know much about DOM and browser-based JavaScript.  A user can crack open a JavaScript console and execute all manner of scripts, including XMLHttpRequests to your server that can be made to look like they came from your own script.  Precautions need to be made on the server for those types of attacks.  Worrying about the security risks *to the DOM or UI* from user input in form fields is silly.

Comment: thanks for the answer! (no the auditor is not worried about harm to servers, he just pointed out that this may be unsafe for the users or something like that). Anyway, I guess it's  non-issue!

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely no XSS problem with that.

What your "validate()" function does is:

1. Via the DOM API, copy a reference to a property of a DOM node (the "value" property of the `<input>` element) to a JavaScript variable.
2. Perform a JavaScript string concatenation operation.  At that point, it absolutely does not matter what the string of characters is.
3. Pass the result string to the `window.alert()`.  The "alert()" function *always* treats its argument strictly as a string. The only "special" character is newline, and all that does is cause text to wrap to a new line.

In particular, note that:

```
     window.alert("<script>var u_r_so_hacked = true;</script>");
```

will show the "" tags just like that, angle brackets and all.

Comment: are you sure about this quote? "The "alert()" function always treats its argument strictly as a string". It does not - if you just put alert(document.cookie); then the resulting alertbox will have the contents of the cookie for the page (not the string document.cookie). In other words document.cookie is evaluated before being given to alert() for display. This is what I'm trying to understand if it can happen or not with my snippet

Comment: Well "document.cookie" **is** a string.  By "treats its argument as a string" I mean that it treats the **value** of the argument as a string. It's just JavaScript; calling alert with a string constant is no different than calling alert with a variable that refers to a string. And, I repeat, your users can **already** get **all** the cookies in their browsers. All of them, without exception. You cannot hide cookie values from your users.